# Seperate items from column B with komma based on items form column A

Tags: excel

Hello in excel i have this tabel:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | A1 |
| A | A2 |
| B | B1 |
| B | B2 |

How do I get it to look like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | A1, A2 |
| B | B1, B2 |

So I want the unique items from column A and the items that belong to them from Column B seperated by a komma.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following formula-

```
=LET(
x,UNIQUE(A2:A5),
y,BYROW(x,LAMBDA(l,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(B2:B5,A2:A5=l)))),
HSTACK(x,y))
```

[image]